# Calculate average number nested series

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to find the length of the `burrito_orders["choice_description"]`.

```
burrito_orders= df[df['item_name'].str.contains('Burrito|burrito')]
         
burrito_orders["length"] = burrito_orders["choice_description"].size
    
burrito_orders
```

Obviously I am getting the number of rows

```
{'order_id': {7: 4},
 'quantity': {7: 1},
 'item_name': {7: 'Steak Burrito'},
 'choice_description': {7: '[Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Black Beans, Pinto Beans, Cheese, Sour Cream, Guacamole, Lettuce]]'},
 'item_price': {7: 11.75},
 'total': {7: 11.75},
 'length': {7: 1172}}
```

How do I grab the number of items of `burrito_orders["choice_description"]` in each row

Comment: Don't post images, transcribing images is tedious. Instead post `df.to_dict()` if `df` is large post `df.head(10).to_dict()` and expected output too.

Comment: good point. Is this more clear?

Comment: What's the expected output of that? And not the downvoter! Do you want to add a new row which keeps track of the count?

Comment: I would like to add a column with the number of items in the `burrito_orders["choice_description"]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
items = burrito_orders["choice_description"][7]      #Getting string value with items
items = items.replace("[","").replace("]","")        #Taking away the square brackets 
items = items.split(",")                             #Creating a list
no_of_items = len(items)                             #Calculate the length of list 
burrito_orders["length"] = no_of_items               #Add to dataframe
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I apply this to every row?

Comment: Replace the first line above to `items = list(burrito_orders["choice_description"].values())[0]` so that it doesn't matter about the product number. Then just create a simple for loop to go through each row and perform the above